# Search string excluding longer string containing substring that contains string, not exclusively longer string

Tags: algorithms, strings, searching

How you define a search of text to find a string A, but exclude results that contains B only (which contains A), but not the both string A and string B?

For example:

- String A : "**Great Wall**"
- String B : "***Great Wall*** of China"
- Text 1: "The **Great Wall**"
- Text 2: "The ***Great Wall*** of China"
- Text 3: "The ***Great Wall*** of China is a **Great Wall**"
- Text 4: "Lorem Ipsum"

I've used Bold to indicate when String A is present and Italics when String B is present.

We would like to search for Texts that contains A, and A + B, but not B only.

So the results should be the Texts 1 and 3.

What approach would enable us to find these results?

Also, we are using a search that can provide us only a list of items that contains a string.

Comment: So the matching sites of A and B should be non-overlapping?

Comment: It can overlap if both strings are in a same result

Comment: Then please give a proper specification of what you want. The example seems to be insufficient.

Comment: How do you find a search string _in what system_?

Comment: What does "A with B" mean?  Can you give a precise statement of the problem?

Comment: I updated the question. @D.W. "A with B" would Text 3 in the examples.

Comment: How about searching for A, and then filtering out all results containing B?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus we might need to keep some of those containing B as they could have a version of A not included in B, like the case of Text 3 shown in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Finite automata to the rescue!

Let

- $\mathcal{A} = \Sigma^* \cdot \{A\} \cdot \Sigma^*$ and
- $\mathcal{B} = \Sigma^* \cdot \{B\} \cdot \Sigma^*$

be the regular languages that contain all strings with substring $A$ resp. $B$.

Note then that

$\qquad\displaystyle L = \overline{\mathcal{B}} \cdot \{A\} \cdot \overline{\mathcal{B}}
\ \cup\  
\mathcal{A} \cdot \mathcal{B} 
\ \cup\  
\mathcal{B} \cdot \mathcal{A}$

is the set of all strings you are looking for, and from basic closure properties of REG we know that it is regular as well.

Constructing a (minimal) DFA from the above description using standard constructions yields an effective method that may or may not be efficient.

Comment: The sets A and B are defined the same way in you answer, but they should be distinct as the string A is a substring of B, but we know search for A will yield results also including B and wants to exclude those containing exclusively B.

Comment: @ceetheman Typo, my bad.